# How to add mulltiple lines of texts to single Radio button

Tags: android

I have radio group on which one of radio button I want add text below to main radio button text.. is it possible ? if I take that single radio button to linear layout or relative layout then I can't select that radio button ... how to add multiple lines of texts to radio button inside radio group in android studio?

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pay_at_clinic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pay_at_clinic"
        android:textColor="@color/sub_text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/pay_online"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/pay_online"
        android:textColor="@color/sub_text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: can us show a screenshot of what u want?

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute used to display multiple lines in a single view

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

Which means that you can add up to two lines of texts.
Depends on the requirement you can change the integer values.

```
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/pay_at_clinic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/pay_at_clinic"
                android:textColor="@color/sub_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

With above code, maximum display lines is 3, after that dot(...) will display.

Comment: and you can use \n for manually moving some text to next line.